# How can I query Firebase Realtime Database by value when it is only a list of key:values?

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database

I have a few collections in a Firebase Realtime Database that are structured like this::

```
{
  "some_collection_name": {
    "randomKey1": "userId1",
    "randomKey2": "userId2",
    "randomKey3": "userId3",
    "randomKey4": "userId1",
    "randomKey5": "userId1"
  }
}
```

I want to query `SomeCollectionName` where the values are equal to `userId1`, but am having a hard time figuring out how to get those values without knowing the key, and not even having any child nodes to perform an `orderByChild` on.

I’m working in a backend environment in pure NodeJS/JavaScript (no Angular).

This seems like it should be a simple task, but I am stuck.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @AlexMamo I've updated the code as fully valid JSON, per your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shoutout to the StackOverflow member who answered this question!

That answer was deleted by an admin (due to my question not being formatted as fully valid JSON -- my bad!), but here is the solution that helped me::

```
// How to get Realtime DB documents by value, using "orderByValue()"

// Collection:
{
  "some_collection_name": {
    "randomKey1": "userId1",
    "randomKey2": "userId2",
    "randomKey3": "userId3",
    "randomKey4": "userId1",
    "randomKey5": "userId1"
  }
}

// Query to get all records where the value = "userId1"
const userId = 'userId1';
const dbRef = app.database()
  .ref('some_collection_name')
  .orderByValue()
  .equalTo(userId);

await dbRef.once('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      const childKey = childSnapshot.key;
      const childData = childSnapshot.val();
      console.log(childKey);
      console.log(childData);
    });
});
```